# Frame around document title, error with mdframed

Tags: errors, titles, mdframed, framed

I have added a frame around my document title using `mdframed`. The document compiles and displays properly but keeps throwing the following error:

```
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end
```

Any ideas about what is happening with this? Here is the syntax being used:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}
\maketitle
\end{mdframed}

%Body text here

\end{document}
```

`mdframed` initialized with:

```
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{MyFrame}{%
    linecolor=black,
    outerlinewidth=2pt,
    %roundcorner=20pt,
    innertopmargin=4pt,
    innerbottommargin=4pt,
    innerrightmargin=4pt,
    innerleftmargin=4pt,
    leftmargin = 4pt,
    rightmargin = 4pt
    %backgroundcolor=gray!50!white}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  i've forgotten whether `mdframed` treats its arguments as list items, but so many unlikely environments do, so it's worth looking at.

Comment: Could you post a compilable code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem if you load `titling` and use the `\maketitlehookx` commands to enter and leave the `mdframed` environnment:

```
\documentclass[11pt, svgnames]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{MyFrame}{%
    linecolor=Tomato,
    outerlinewidth=2,
    roundcorner=10pt,
    innertopmargin=15pt,
    innerbottommargin=4pt,
    innerrightmargin=4pt,
    innerleftmargin=4pt,
    leftmargin = 4pt,
    rightmargin = 4pt,
    backgroundcolor=WhiteSmoke
}
 \author{Edward Lear}
 \title{The Quangle Wangle’s Hat}
 \date{(n.\,d.)}

\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{\begin{mdframed}[style = MyFrame]}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookd}{\end{mdframed}\vspace{5ex}}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\settowidth{\versewidth}{For his Hat was a hundred and two feet wide,}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
\begin{altverse}
  On the top of the Crumpetty Tree\\
      The Quangle Wangle sat,\\
But his face you could not see,\\
      On account of his Beaver Hat.\\
For his Hat was a hundred and two feet wide,\\
With ribbons and bibbons on every side\\
And bells, and buttons, and loops, and lace,\\
So that nobody ever could see the face\\
            Of the Quangle Wangle Quee.
\end{altverse}
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works beautifully! Thank you Bernard! I wasn't familiar with the `\maketitlehook` command.